# Create new directory with batch file (MKDIR not working)?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I tried using at first a combination of xcopy and del, but del kept failing.

xcopy creates directory if it doesn't yet exist.

The other option is to use MKDIR but it does not work inside a batch file?

```
MKDIR "C:\stuff"
```

Any ideas why this is not working inside .bat/.cmd file??

It works fine from a command prompt.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Provide real example so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 16):

Try using `md` instead of `mkdir`

```
md "c:\stuff"
```

This has always worked for me.

Comment: That is actually just an [alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32370298/7111561) and both do exactly the same ...

Answer (score 3):

In Windows Vista, 7, and 8, there is a feature called [User Account Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). To make a new folder in just any location, you need to be running an "elevated command prompt," which is running Command Prompt as an administrator.